# Using EWS to create appointments. For one, and only one, of our users EWS returns an error with an incorrect GUID for the mailbox

Tags: office365, office365api

For the past two weeks, when attempting to create an appointment for a specific user, EWS returns the following:

```
The specified object was not found in the store.
Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: [xxxx]
because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information.
The mailbox may have been moved recently.
```

This mailbox has existed for over 6 years, and we've never had this issue before.

The most interesting part to me is that the GUID returned in the error message doesn't match the GUID of the user's mailbox.

Comment: Strange question. Is there any obvious difference between this client and other clients?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix the issue. It seems the user's mailbox/calendar had a corrupt or outdated set of rules.

All I had to do we move the mailbox from Powershell using:

```
New-MoveRequest -Identity "username"
```

After about 10 minutes I checked the status of the move and it was complete. I tested the code to create the appointment with EWS and it worked!